# Rotating youtube video

Tags: html, css, api, youtube, rotation

I'm using html. I have embedded a Youtube video via youtube api. The page i'm working on meant to used by mobile users. So the problem is when the user clicks the fullscreen button on the video, it automatically goes wide screen. Like rotates 90 degree.

Comment: What is your question, what do you have problem with?

Comment: My question is, whenever user fullscreens youtube video embed, video automatically goes landscape mode. (for mobile). Like in the youtube app.

Comment: that's not a question. I don't understand what are you asking.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I'm trying to say **i want the video go to landscape orientation when the user clicks fullscreen button**

Comment: Now I understand. 
There is no way you can controll this behaviour. When user switch the video to fullscreen, it fully depends on the mobile platform. User have to manualy rotate mobile phone to watch fullscreen landscape video.

Comment: But in the youtube app, it forces user to watch in landscape ? However, thank you for your effort.